# Publishing just controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I'm editing views or other non-dll files, I can press `CTRL + ; + P` to publish that file to the web-server. However, it doesn't work for controllers, probably because they will be compiled into a dll file.

Is there any way to compile and publish just the dll file and avoid the long delay of publishing the whole project?

*EDIT*

Thanks to Sarvjeet, I know that I can build the project and copy the dll file, I can also script this in post-build event of the project like this:

```
copy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\$(TargetFileName)"
```

I was hoping for a better way, that lets me use the short-key, `CTRL + ; + P`, and takes publishing profile into account.

Answer (score 3):

Copy compiled DLL and pasted it to deployed folder. You don't need to deploy whole project.

Comment: Thanks Sarvjeet, I know that I can compile the project and copy the dll to the root project. I can also write a post-build script to do that. But I was looking for a clean and automated way that takes publish profile into account... .